# jquery tab not opening

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm trying to open a tab after dynamically creating it but I can't seem to get the newly created tab to open. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong
See my code below

```
    var num_tabs = $("div#supplierTabs ul li").length + 1;
    var dd = document.getElementById("dd_resortList")

    $("div#supplierTabs ul").append(
        "<li><a href='#fragment" + num_tabs + "'>" + dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text + "</a></li>"
    );

    $("div#supplierTabs").append("<div id='fragment" + num_tabs + "'>text " + num_tabs + "</div>")

    $("div#supplierTabs").tabs("refresh");

    $("div#supplierTabs").tabs("load", num_tabs-1);
```

Comment: Please create a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) which illustrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer : -

```
    $("div#supplierTabs").tabs("option", "active", num_tabs - 1);
```

This opens the last tab

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('the name of your class or id').tabs();
});
</script>


<div class="whatever you want but must be equal the class or id of your qjquery function">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about2">About2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about3">About3</a></li>
        </ul>
            <div id="about"><p> Your Text </p></div>
            <div id="about2"><p>Your Text</p></div>
            <div id="about3"><p>Your Text</p></div>
</div>
```